# My object is not showing up when I render but is showing up elsewhere

Tags: modeling, rendering, camera

Here is my object in render
[Object when rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTPlK.png)

Here is my object in layout [Object when not rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66kQ.jpg)

[This is a dropbox link to download my file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/m32jr9how3e4mib/donut.blend?dl=0)

The camera icon for my object is checked aswell. Can anyone tell me how to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Go to the *Particle Properties > Render* and enable *Show Emitter*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my object not show up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up) (See No. 23)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the *Show Emitter* option:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I must have clicked it by accident.

Comment: If so, please consider to accept the answer @kmcb How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour